# How to reference a VueJS child component from a parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In VueJS 3, assuming I have the following component template for a small "html block editor":

```
<!--Block Editor-->
<template>
    <div>
        <content-block-ui-frame>
            <content-block-type1></content-block-type1>
        </content-block-ui-frame>

        <content-block-ui-frame>
            <content-block-type2></content-block-type2>
        </content-block-ui-frame>

        <content-block-ui-frame>
            <content-block-type3></content-block-type3>
        </content-block-ui-frame>
    </div>
</template>
```

`content-block-ui-frame` looks like this:

```
     <template>
        <div class="container">
            <slot />          
        </div>
     </template>
```

So, `slot` contains an instance of the `content-block-typeX` components.
From within this `content-block-ui-frame` component, how can I reference the slotted component?

I need to get at the slotted `content-block-typeX`'s Data as well as the Methods.  Is that possible?  I've tried with `ref` but couldn't seem to get it work.

The goal is to encapsulate a particular block's Data structure and Methods inside the block component itself and somehow publish these out to the containing block editor for editing/saving/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be creating a ref for each content-block-ui-frame in the block-editor, and passing the ref to the right content-block-ui-frame as a prop.
Is this the approach you meant when you mentioned you already tried it with refs?

**EDIT**: I was able to create a minimal example where passing the ContentBlock ref as a prop to the ContentblockUiFrame works as expected.
The ContentBlockUIFrame components are able to use the methods of ContentBlock.

Check my example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-hofstadter-fy0ue?file=/src/App.vue)

```js
import ContentBlock from "./components/ContentBlock.vue";
import ContentBlockUiFrame from "./components/ContentBlockUiFrame.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  components: { ContentBlock, ContentBlockUiFrame },
  setup() {
    const contentBlockOne = ref(null);
    const contentBlockTwo = ref(null);

    return {
      contentBlockOne,
      contentBlockTwo,
    };
  },
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="block-editor">
    <content-block-ui-frame :content-block="contentBlockOne">
      <content-block content="Content one" ref="contentBlockOne" />
    </content-block-ui-frame>

    <content-block-ui-frame :content-block="contentBlockTwo">
      <content-block content="Content two" ref="contentBlockTwo" />
    </content-block-ui-frame>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Yes.  The ref references for slotted components are always null.  Refs for other things work fine.

Comment: @user1142433 I updated my answer with a working example, feel free to take a look.